# Can multiple Lambda functions write to a single DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am planning to design a DynamoDB schema that can be used by multiple Lambda functions for a write operation.

Is it possible to achieve this? if yes, is it a good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and it's common practice.